# Can I re-whip whipped cream?

Tags: whipped-cream

I whipped some cream with soft peaks and put it in the fridge. A few days most of it has collapsed and is liquid. Can I re-whip it effectively without adding more cream?

Answer (score 23):

If you try to re-whip the cream now, it'll likely turn into butter, not whipped cream. The initial whipping process has already caused the fat in the cream to coalesce; further whipping now will complete that process, similar to if you had over-whipped the cream in the first place.

Comment: I wonder what would be the outcome of using a whipping siphon with collapsed cream

Comment: @Agos I would expect better results from a siphon, since much less mechanical agitation (which would squeeze fat globules together) is occurring. In fact, the mechanism of a whipping siphon is not hugely different from that of a milk homogenizer.

Answer (score 5):

Sneftel answered the question you asked, but to answer a corollary question: you can prevent this from happening by using a stabilizer (also called a cream stiffener).  One you can get is by Dr. Oetker and is called Whip It (or Sahnesteif).  There are [a few other alternatives](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-whipped-cream-stabilizer-1446455) as well.

Comment: Another way to prevent the cream from collapsing is to store it in a manner that limits air contact. For instance, I store whipped cream in a Tupperware container, but before putting the lid on, I smooth a piece of plastic wrap down right against the surface of the whipped cream, then put the lid on.